# How do I beat campaign level 29?

Tags: worms-2-armageddon

How do I beat campaign level 29 in Worms 2: Armageddon?
Even with the best strategies I am able to get down to 1 enemy, who I have to go to because they don't teleport to me. When I do teleport, they just use their perfect aimbot to kill my low HP worms. And if somehow I have high HP, they just use their overpowered weapons and still win.